# Pass text and categorie value to database (node,react,mongodb)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, nodes

hello guys I'm new to react, node, I want when creating a post to pass the text and the category value (catg in the schema).

I was able to pass the text and create the post, but I want also to add a category when creating the post

this is the route for creating the post

```
router.post('/', [auth, [
        check('text', 'text is required').not().isEmpty()

    ]],

    async(req, res) => {

        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        try {
            const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password'); //don't want to send password back
            const newPost = new Post({
                text: req.body.text,
                name: user.name,
                avatar: user.avatar,
                user: req.user.id,
                //catg:req.
            })
            const post = await newPost.save();
            res.json(post);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error');

        }

    });
```

this is the action to add the post

```
export const addPost = formData => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/posts', formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Post Created', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

this the post schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  isApproved: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  catg: {
    type: String,
    default: '0'
  },
  likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      }
    }
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      avatar: {
        type: String
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi guys it was very simple I just add the value of category when creating the post and it works

```
 onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      addPost({ text,value });
      setText('');
    }}
```

thank you guys